# using an external monitor as an extension makes my touch screen HP TX2 no longer work as touch screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

i have an hp tx2 tablet. when i plug in an external monitor the touch screen function no longer works properly, when i touch the screen it is as if i have touched the external monitor, so i cant use the touch function on the tablet screen. has anyone had this problem, or can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem & seem to have resolved it finally.

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution

Advanced Settings > Properties (ATI Radeon HD 3200) > Driver - Just clicked Roll Back Driver.

Seems to work more or less the same.

Comment: hi karl, thats fantastic it worked perfectly. thank you.